# Load the output of Store module in menu opencart2

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x, ocmod

I have a "Store" module and I need to put the output of it in the menu which is rendered by /catalog/view/theme/journal2/template/journal2/menu/main.tpl

It's controller is in catalog/controller/journal2/menu.php

What I have tried :

```
 <file path="catalog/controller/journal2/menu.php">
    <operation>
    <search><![CDATA[$this->template = $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/journal2/menu/main.tpl';]]></search>
    <add position="before"><![CDATA[
    $data['ac_all_stores'] = $this->load->controller('module/store');
    ]]></add>
    </operation>
</file>
```

and

```
 <file path="catalog/controller/module/store.php">
    <operation>
    <search><![CDATA[return $this->load->view($this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/module/store.tpl', $data);]]></search>
    <add position="after"><![CDATA[
    $this->load->view($this->config->get('config_template') . 'template/journal2/menu/main.tpl', $data);
    ]]></add>
    </operation>
</file>
```

But none of these works. Output of the module is still not visible in menu's main.tpl Can anyone please tel how to do it right? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve that by putting

```
    $this->data['ac_all_stores'] = $this->load->controller('module/store');
```

instead of

```
   $data['ac_all_stores'] = $this->load->controller('module/store');
```